# Watson Dialog service to Conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-dialog, watson-conversation

We created dialogs with Bluemix Dialog service and now we would like to import them into the new Bluemix Conversation service.
The export-import failed.
Do you know if an transfert process exists ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the ability to migrate to Conversation from Dialog is not possible, as the two systems are very different.

**Intents** in Conversation are similar to NLC. So if you have an existing NLC service, you can export that and import as a CSV file.

**Entities** in Conversation are not at all related to the same in Dialog.

Conversation itself is stateless. All conversational state, context variables need to be maintained at the application layer. Where as Dialog would normally maintain that.

In Dialog What you would define as an `INPUT` + `OUTPUT` nodes are now a single node in Conversation.

`GOTO` is now `Continue from`. But a continue from will have different behaviours depending if you hook it to "wait for user input", "condition" or "message".

Fuzzy matching what you would normally do with Variations is now handled by coding in condition blocks, or at the application layer.